# Unable to start Nginx server in ubuntu server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Unable to start nginx server OS: ubuntu server 16.04

systemctl status nginx.status
is throwing this message:
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-12-08 14:38:39 UTC; 19min ago
  Process: 2560 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        fastcgi_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/cache/fcgi levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=1h;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

sites-enabled file :

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name timeskannada.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_cache  microcache;
                fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
                fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 30s;
                fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
                fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
                fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
                fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 200;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: [emerg] 2925#2925: "if" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6
getting this error in my error log

Comment: ... and there's no "if" in your configs. Try to update config paths and check that you are looking at correct files. Also try running `nginx -t` directly and post results.

Comment: nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: got above message for nginx -t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with Ithemes security rules in `nginx.conf` which added if directives in the begining of the file

Comment: Can you post an example so this can serve as an example what other should look into facing such problems?

Comment: wodpress plugin ithemes security edited /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and added some rules at the begining of the file starting with

Comment: # BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
 # Enable HackRepair.com's blacklist feature - Security > Settings > Banned Users > Default Blacklist
 # Start HackRepair.com Blacklist
 # Start Abuse Agent Blocking

Comment: this code which caused this error after commenting those rules nginx worked very well

Comment: Need to place these rules of ithemes securit inside

Comment: server {} refer nginx documentation for more info